# How to copy file contents to clipboard

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So basically i want to copy the contents of this file to my clipboard 
Ive tried many things like using different modules and such but for some reason i just cant do it

```
    import shutil
    owl_hub = open('owlhub.txt','r')
    if a == "Owl Hub":
        lbl.config(text = owl_hub.readlines())
        shutil.copy(owlhub.readlines())
```

Comment: Read [You need to understand the concept of file pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771555/7414759),  you can't use `.readlines()` twice. I dind't see any attemp to use `clipboard`?

Comment: Clipboard as in for copying and pasting and also that link you sent actually really helped me

Comment: ok so i figured out teh right syntax the only problem now is that its saying permission denied file acces

Comment: ***permission denied file acces***: At the `.copy(...` statement? If yes, your shown statement looks wrong.

Comment: it works with txts in the same file but it cant acces that certain file because im not running it on an elevated level

Comment: Try running this program in terminal, but open cmd with admin access.

Comment: ive tried that but i can tseem to find the right directory to get to desktop

Answer (score 0):

Use tkinter; it comes with python and provides a cross-platform way to change the clipboard

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.clipboard_clear()
with open('owlhub.txt') as f:
    root.clipboard_append(f.read().strip())
root.update()
root.destroy()
```